# Responsive CSS layout - how to stretch the background overlay

Tags: html, css

I am building a website with a responsive CSS layout: I have two sections here, "third" and "footer". I would like to stretch the background of third to cover up the whitespace that I have between "third" and "footer".

Here is the HTML that I am using:

```
    <!-- Third -->
        <section id="third" class="main">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <h2>keep in touch</h2>
                    <p>we'd love to hear from you. send us your questions and comments.</p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div class="content dark style3 featured">
                <div class="container small">
                    <form method="post" action="#">
                        <div class="row half">
                            <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                            <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row half">
                            <div class="12u"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <ul class="actions">
                                    <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                    <li><input type="reset" class="button alt" value="Clear Form" /></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    <!-- Footer -->
        <section id="footer">
    <div class="content style3 featured">
            <ul class="icons">
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="fa fa-twitter solo"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook solo"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com" class="fa fa-instagram solo"><span>Instagram</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com" class="fa fa-pinterest solo"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.flickr.com" class="fa fa-flickr solo"><span>Flickr</span></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        </section>

</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
    .main
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

    .main > header
    {
        background: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5em 0 5em 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

        .main > header h2
        {
            font-size: 2.25em;
            font-weight: 100;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .main > header p
        {
            margin: 2em 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }

    .main > .content
    {
        padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
    }

        .main > .content > .container
        {
        }
   .main > .content.style3
        {
            background: url('images/bgtr.svg') top right no-repeat,
                        url('images/bgbl.svg') bottom left no-repeat,
                        url('images/overlay.png'),
                        linear-gradient(45deg, #5f796b, #3a4e59, #2f394e);
        }
```

This is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBtng.jpg
How would I be able to fill in that whitespace?

Here is the CSS for the sections:

```
        section,
    article
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    section > :last-child,
    article > :last-child
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    section:last-child,
    article:last-child
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .row > section,
    .row > article
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
```

The section article did have a margin-bottom of 3em, but I changed it to 0, and I still see the whitespace.

Comment: We need to see the CSS that is being applied to the section tag. To me this looks like there's a margin-bottom on section tags. Set that to 0, and the gap should close. BTW, in general, it's best to set a full-page background image on element that contains all of your sections -- e.g. the body element, or on .main here.

Comment: I added in the CSS for the sections. I did change the margin-bottom to 0, but I still see the whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared an example for you. You can benefit from this example.

See this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/gFlrm)

Also i will give you the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text_wrap">
    <div class="div_text">
<input type='text' class='cc-mask' placeholder='Name'/>
    </div>
    <div class="div_text">
<input type='text' class='cc-mask' placeholder='Surname'/>
    </div>
    <div class="message_text">
      <input type='text' class='message-mask' placeholder='Message Here'/>

    </div>
    <div class="send_message_clearform_wrap">
      <div class="send_message">
        <input type="submit" class="sendButton" value="Send Message" />
      </div>
      <div class="clear_form">
        <input type="submit" class="clearButton" value="Celar Form" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="white_area"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-image: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #188aad 0%,#00a698 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #188aad 0%,#00a698 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #188aad 0%,#00a698 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #188aad 0%,#00a698 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #188aad 0%,#00a698 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.container {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  margin:10px auto;
}
.div_text {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.cc-mask {
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  font-size:18px;
  background:none;
  border-radius:3px;
  border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding:2px;
  outline:none;
  width:250px;

}
.message-mask {
  display:inline-block;
  height:250px;
  font-size:18px;
  background:none;
  border:1px solid #c1c1c1;
  padding:2px;
  outline:none;
  width:518px;
  margin-left:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
.message_text {
  float:left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.sendButton {
    width: 220px;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: #fff;
    font: normal 11px/24px "Lucida Grande";
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-image: rgba(235,235,235,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb5a17 0%,#eb5a17 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb5a17 0%,#eb5a17 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb5a17 0%,#eb5a17 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb5a17 0%,#eb5a17 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #eb5a17 0%,#eb5a17 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(128,128,128,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px, inset rgba(255,255,255,1) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.send_message {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:56px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
.clear_form{
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:56px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:30px;
}
.clearButton {
    width: 220px;
    height: 54px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
  border-radius:3px;
    font: normal 11px/24px "Lucida Grande";
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";       /* IE 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;          /* Netscape */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;        /* Safari 1.x */
opacity: 0.5;  
}
.white_area {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that I just had to add some color codes in the body. It had a background value of #FFF which was where the whitespace was coming in.